# Create a Linux shell script program that sorts the numbers and words in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to create a Linux shell script program that reads a text file (until EOF) and does the following things:

- determines whether each line contains a word or a number
- keeps count of how many words are found
- append each word found into a text file (e.g. wordsfile.txt)
- append each number found into a text file (e.g. numbersfile.txt)
- return all of the following information

The text file that I want the program to read is as follows:

```
123
apple
456
boy
789
```

And I want the output to be as follows:

```
2 WORDS, 3 NUMBERS
```

Plus, I want the wordsfile.txt to read:

```
apple
boy
```

And the numbersfile.txt to read:

```
123
456
789
```

This is my code:

```
#!bin/bash
wordcount=0
numbercount=0
while read line; dp
  for word in $line; do
    $wordcount = $wordcount + 1
    echo word >> /words/wordsfile.txt
  done
  for number in $line; do
    $numbercount = $numbercount + 1
    echo number >> /numbers/numbersfile.txt
  done
  echo $wordcount " WORDS, " $numberscount " NUMBERS"
done
```

And this is the output that I'm getting:

```
./assignment6.sh < assignment6file.txt
./assignment6.sh: line 5: 0: command not found
./assignment6.sh: line 6: /words/wordfile.txt: No such file or directory
./assignment6.sh: line 9: 0: command not found
./assignment6.sh: line 10: /numbers/numbersfile.txt: No such file or directory
0  words,  0  numbers
./assignment6.sh: line 5: 0: command not found
./assignment6.sh: line 6: /words/wordfile.txt: No such file or directory
./assignment6.sh: line 9: 0: command not found
./assignment6.sh: line 10: /numbers/numbersfile.txt: No such file or directory
0  words,  0  numbers
./assignment6.sh: line 5: 0: command not found
./assignment6.sh: line 6: /words/wordfile.txt: No such file or directory
./assignment6.sh: line 9: 0: command not found
./assignment6.sh: line 10: /numbers/numbersfile.txt: No such file or directory
0  words,  0  numbers
./assignment6.sh: line 5: 0: command not found
./assignment6.sh: line 6: /words/wordfile.txt: No such file or directory
./assignment6.sh: line 9: 0: command not found
./assignment6.sh: line 10: /numbers/numbersfile.txt: No such file or directory
0  words,  0  numbers
./assignment6.sh: line 5: 0: command not found
./assignment6.sh: line 6: /words/wordfile.txt: No such file or directory
./assignment6.sh: line 9: 0: command not found
./assignment6.sh: line 10: /numbers/numbersfile.txt: No such file or directory
0  words,  0  numbers
```

I don't understand why my code isn't working. Please help.

Comment: The first error Bash reports is `line 5: 0: command not found`. This means it tried to call the function or program `0`, but couldn’t find it. You don’t explicitly call `0`, but something in that line makes Bash try anyway. This is usually variable expansion.

Comment: After changing the `dp` to `do` on line 4, [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) lists a bunch of warnings; you should check them out. (Unfortunately I can’t find a way to link to specifically checking your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux has all these neat utilities to match numbers and words and to count them. No need to reinvent the wheel.

```
wf=wordsfile.txt
nf=numbersfile.txt
egrep -i '^[a-z]+$' $1 > $wf
egrep '^[0-9.]+$' $1 > $nf
W=`wc -l $wf`
N=`wc -l $nf`
echo $W WORDS, $N NUMBERS
```

Save as a script, then run like this:

```
./my-script file-to-read
```